# Email attach multiple .CSV in zip file: google app engine python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

How do i attach `.zip` containing multiple `.csv` file. ex. `text_1.csv, text_2.csv`

Remember, These csv files constructed from the data in the datastore.

`message = mail.EmailMessage()`

```
message.attachments = .... #??
message.send()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you want this???

```
import zipfile, StringIO
o=StringIO.StringIO()
file = zipfile.ZipFile(file=o,compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED,mode="w")
.. . ## add your csv files here
file.close()
o.seek(0)
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] ='application/zip'
self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="your_csvs.zip"'
self.response.out.write(o.getvalue())
```

for more info visit: http://www.tareandshare.com/2008/09/28/Zip-Google-App-Engine-GAE/

Comment: i think, these files are not on filesystem.
its generated in-memory only.

Comment: they; generate in-memory zip file

Comment: Actually I am constructing a csv file from data in the datastore. & then want to zipping it up..!!